# HTML5 Canvas Base64 Error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

Any idea why this code is not working? :\

Demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/vgmFN/89/

```
 <script>
        var imgObj1 = new Image();
        var img = new Image();var a1=0;
        var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
        var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
        imgObj1.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj1,1,1);a1 = 1;
        }
        imgObj1.src = 'favicon.ico';
        if (a1 == 1) {
        console.log(can.toDataURL())
        img.src = can.toDataURL();
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        a1=0;
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave `imgObj1` time to load with `imgObj1.onload`, but you must also give `img` time to load by adding `img.onload`

https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tf0y1pL9/

[image]

BTW, errors are easier to spot if you format your code. ;-)

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

// create and load the first image
var imgObj1 = new Image();
imgObj1.onload = function() {

    ctx.drawImage(imgObj1,1,1);

    // create and load the canvas as an image
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.src = can.toDataURL();

}
imgObj1.src = '/favicon.ico';
```

Comment: Why would it to load var img?
Arent we just doing toDataURL which is js internal function?

Comment: `toDataURL` will execute synchronously, but all images are loaded asynchronously. So in your code `document.body.appendChild(img);` will be executed before `img` is fully loaded and ready to use.